# Rank change - So big increase?

Tags: support, reputation-leagues

On Stack Overflow, There are users with rank change +20,000

How is that possible? As you can see on image, my "opponent" has got almost same week rank but has change 10x bigger. So, how is that achievable?

[image: ??]

EDIT: I got it. however I have no idea why does everyone rock me down with downvotes. I was just curious ...

Comment: Are you reading **rep** or **rank**?

Comment: whoops, sorry. My question has been edited.

Comment: This is just *rank*. Scorpi0 was on a much lower rank than you last week.

Comment: but his last answer is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3138742/which-query-is-better-and-efficient-mysql/3138863#3138863 Jun 29 '10, so how's that possible!?

Comment: @genesis you are mistaken. See his [activity tab](http://stackoverflow.com/users/128662/scorpi0?tab=activity).

Comment: and now look mine http://stackoverflow.com/users/764846/genesis?tab=reputation I have 418+ rep in last 2 days

Comment: @genesis you are misunderstanding the concept of *rank*. You were on a higher rank last week already, while the other user did not earn any reputation. Therefore, your growth *in rank* is relatively small. The other user started at 0 (or some other very low number), which is why their *relative rank* grew much more than yours.

Comment: so if I would have rep0 at start of week, and reached 1000 to end of the week, I would get MORE ranks than if I would start with 2000 and end up with 3000?

Comment: @genesis exactly. It's just the *relative* growth of your position. If I earn 10000 dollars in month 1, and 10010 dollars in month 2, my *growth* is just 10 dollars, but I would still be stinking rich. (Well, kind of.) If somebody earns 0 dollars in month 1, but 300 dollars in month 2, their growth is 300 dollars - but they're still poor.

Comment: great. I'll rather delete this thread. Thank you all

Comment: one more question - If I earn 10 000 $ in month 1, and in 2 i'll earn 300$ - and  If I earn 0$ in month 1, and in 2 I'll earn 300$ - second case does got a lot more rank change, right?

Comment: @genesis yup, because there are more users between 0$ and 300$ than there are between 300$ and 10000$.

Comment: you wanted to tell "between 0$ and 300$ than there are between 10300$ and 10000$" right?

Comment: @genesis yeah! That's what I meant.

Comment: once more: "There are more users which has ALLTIME money between 0$ and 300$ ......" or "There are more users which has growth  this week (relatively from last week) money between 0$ and 300$ ......" ?

Comment: Your change in weekly rank shows on the weekly league; your change in all-time rank shows on the all-time league.  Weekly league rank is by weekly earnings, i.e. change in reputation since the previous week.

Comment: so first week I'll receive 200 and next week I'll receive 200, rank change will be 0, in most cases, 0 ?

Comment: Yes, a change in rank indicates a change in rate of earning since the previous period.  No change in rate of earning will result in a small rank change.

Comment: YES! EXACTLY! Can you submit it as an answer please?EDIT:but he's week rank #516, how is that possible? He's first in rank change order...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To understand how weekly rankings work, use the "prev week" link to compare results.

This week for scorpi0:

> Rank: #516, Weekly rep: 317

Last week for scorpi0:

> Rank: #23910, Weekly rep: -4

So last week, scorpi0 earned rock-bottom reputation earnings.  That put him/her almost at the very bottom of **all** users.  This week, scorpi0 was active and earned (so far) a respectable amount of reputation.  Only about 500 users on all of Stack Overflow earned 300 or more repuation points so far this week.

So scorpi0 went from all the way at the bottom to within 500 from the top since last week.  That is why his/her weekly rank changed so dramatically from one week to the next: **a dramatic increase in weekly reputation earnings**.

All-time reputation and all-time ranking will be **much less susceptible** to large changes like this.  Weekly reputation rank changes aren't affected by total reputation so there can be wild swings from week to week.  If you tend to earn the same amount of reputation from week to week, your weekly rank will not change very much over time.

Comment: I still do not know why everyone striked me down with downvotes. I was just misunderstanding how does that work. You are here to help people, so why you rock everyone who don't get something?

Comment: because (a) you said that there is a "bad counting" bug (b) in meta downvotes indicate disagreement ( [faq] ) ergo, downvotes indicate your understanding that it was a bug is incorrect @genesis

Comment: You can see the breakdown in your own reputation tab here on meta but at the moment you got 5 upvotes and 7 downvotes so you still get a net reputation increase.  You tested the waters and came out unscathed!

Comment: what about accept percentage? It's in negative right now

Answer (score 3):

Evidently there were 23394 people with between 1175-1492 rep, and only 2469 with between 252-561 rep. There were just more people for him to pass in the rep range he was moving through.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34371/can-we-view-the-reputation-distribution/34392#34392

Comment: My all-time rank with rep 757 is #25779. Do you really think there are 20 000 people between 1175 - 1492 rep and 5770 people have the rest?

Comment: @random: rep10 has about 11 000 members? So where is that magic number 23394 ?

Comment: Run the numbers on the reputation and the count of users on each band. It keeps changing with each dump. @gen

Comment: @gen - look at the Total Reputation breakdown on the right side: http://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/alltime/stackoverflow/2008-07-31/446591?sort=reputationchange#446591 . And then go kick back and relax, it's not that important.

Comment: I did not say it'S important, I'm just curious how is that possible. He received about 210 rep today, yesterday, day before yesterday and I received 410 in same period of time.