# Why is there such a difference in the change column?

Tags: support, reputation, reputation-leagues

This is a follow up question to this question:

*[Rank change - So big increase?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95648/rank-change-so-big-increase)*

This is my current ranking:

[image: My Current Ranking]

And this is another ranking:

[image: Another guy's change]

How come my change is that much greater if we got the same exact reputation, but Ahmad got 1504 year reputation, while I got only 579?

Answer (score 8):

The change is the delta between this year's rank and last year's rank. Your rank each year is determined by your yearly rep, not your total rep. Your total rep value of 4,078 is shown there for informational purposes only but is not a factor in calculating the annual change figure.

- This year your rank is [#32487](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/year/stackoverflow/2019-01-01/1164004#1164004). That means that 32486 people earned more rep than you this year.
- Last year your rank was #51304 because you earned 454 rep and 51303 people earned more than that.

You earned a little more rep than last year hence your increase of +18810 given the large number of people on Stack Overflow.

- Ahmad on the other hand has a rank of #9916 based on the 1,504 rep he earned this year.
- However last year he was ranked #16882 because he gained 1,188 rep.

So his change is the difference between being ranked #9916 and being ranked #16882 i.e. smaller than yours and that is principally because he is getting more rep than you each year.

There are fewer people that get 1000+ rep per year than manage to get 500 rep per year so that his change values are smaller than yours is basically down to that single reason.

There is a separate page that shows [your rank based on your total rep](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/alltime/stackoverflow). Your all time rank is #43956 there (enter your name in the search box to find it) and Ahmed's all time rank is #43953 i.e. basically the same as yours.

Comment: Also worth remembering that its the votes a person gets in a year not the posstive contribution they made in the year, so for example most of my rank is due to past activities.

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing surprising here. This is not a ranking of total reputation, but of how much reputation you gained this year, so your total reputation being the same is irrelevant. If you look at the sidebar:

```
Rep  Change*  Users
10,000+       706
5,000+        1,914
2,500+        5,040
1,000+        16,733
500+          38,557
250+          82,183
100+          183,861
50+           262,131
1+            431,332
```

You'll see that there are *far* more people with small changes than there are with large changes, so if you move a bit in the lower ranks, you jump over a lot of people. Ahmad Abdelghany [got 1188 rep](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/year/stackoverflow/2018-01-01/1998422?sort=reputationchange#1998422) last year, so he was already much higher up in the rankings last year. Hence his change this year isn't much. You [got 454 rep last year](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/year/stackoverflow/2018-01-01/1164004?sort=reputationchange#1164004), and so you jumped over tens of thousands of people when you got 579 this year.