# What does "change" mean in the reputation leagues?

Tags: support, reputation-leagues

I am wondering what the term 'change' actually means in the [reputation leagues](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/year/stackoverflow/2021-01-01?sort=reputationchange).

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is there such a difference in the change column?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/337869/why-is-there-such-a-difference-in-the-change-column)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It compares the current league with the period before. You're looking at the yearly rank, so it compares your ranking in 2021 (so far), which is #9649, with your ranking in 2020, which is 9649 + 563245 = #572894.