# Data Dump Logic Errors

Tags: discussion, data-dump

While trying to do some stats for the '[critical mass](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10472/is-there-a-critical-mass-of-answers-or-reputation)' question I ran into some logic errors in the data dump that made generating the statistics impossible. I'm not sure if the errors are on my end or not, so simply telling me whether or not you get the same results would be helpful.

The following are the errors I found (which may or may not actually exist):

View count is an attribute of Questions, not answers - 5 Results.

```
SELECT COUNT( * ) 
FROM posts 
WHERE ViewCount !=0
AND PostTypeId =2
ORDER BY ViewCount ASC
```

Post was edited before it was created - 4 results.

```
SELECT COUNT( * ) 
FROM posts
WHERE LastEditDate < CreationDate
AND LastEditDate !=0
AND CreationDate !=0
```

An answer contains tags - 1 result

```
SELECT COUNT( * ) 
FROM posts
WHERE Tags != ""
AND PostTypeId =2
```

Answer was created before its question - 93 results

```
SELECT COUNT( * ) 
FROM posts v1
JOIN posts v2 ON ( v1.ParentId = v2.Id ) 
WHERE v1.CreationDate < v2.CreationDate
```

Comments created before before a post - 47 results

```
SELECT COUNT( * ) 
FROM comments
LEFT JOIN posts ON ( comments.PostId = posts.Id ) 
WHERE comments.CreationDate < posts.CreationDate
```

Additionally, simply for completion, OwnerId="" when users have been deleted. This issue has already been resolved and will be removed from subsequent dumps.

---

The error that actually stemmed this post was

```
SELECT COUNT( * ) 
FROM votes
LEFT JOIN posts ON ( votes.PostId = posts.Id ) 
WHERE votes.CreationDate < posts.CreationDate
```

but I have since remembered that the original vote table has dates rounded down to the nearest day.

Comment: I get nada on StatOverflow. You nuke it? I wanted to see who was psychic. I mean, there are obvious candidates, but it piqued my interest.

Comment: I'm migrating the server but I don't want to carry over all the errors if they're on my end since it's a considerable amount of IO.