# Why is 15 rep required to upvote on Super User when I have >100 rep on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, reputation, voting, privileges

When I google something and I find the answer on Stack Overflow, I always upvote the question and any useful answers.  I can't do this on Super User or any other SE site, because I don't ask or answer questions on those sites. Why? I understand the anti-spam reason for the 15 rep minimum, but why do you apply that same minimum value to users that are demonstrably active on another SE site? All it does is preventing me from adding value by upvoting useful content.

Answer (score 13):

This is already in place, but to be "demonstrably active" the system requires 200 reputation, not 100 as you suggest. Once you reach 200 on any site, you will get a bonus of 100 on all your linked accounts (including the one that reached 200).

Comment: Heh did you get a lot of upvotes because you're mod or because you have got a lot of rep already?

Comment: @genesis: Could be, or maybe they felt I explained it more clearly. Looks like I was the only one who upvoted you for some reason.

Comment: I think there was a question about this... oh, here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/515/the-problem-with-reputation-does-high-reputation-attract-too-many-up-votes

Comment: 100 was just an example, I was not suggesting that value had any meaning in particular. By "demonstrably active" what I really meant was "not a shill or bot". Whether it's 200 or 100 or whatever, A) it's not presented to me as a user, I simply get an error that says I can't upvote and B) it still seems too high (which is of course subjective). Also the massive bonus at 200 seems both extraordinarily arbitrary and excessively large.

Answer (score 2):

I was thinking about this yesterday. But answer is simple. If you receive > 200 reputation on SO, you'll get 100 rep bonus on each site you're & you'll connect with, and then you are able to upvote.