# Stable answer ordering while staying fair

Tags: feature-request, answers, sorting, answer-order

Currently answers with equal score are ordered randomly on each page request. I understand that this is intended to make voting fairer. But that the order changes each time you refresh the page is a bit annoying.

What I'd prefer is an ordering that keeps the fairness, but doesn't change all the time. My answer to this is to combine the user id and the answer id as secondary score criterion.

When looking at a single page this is practically indistinguishable from the current sort order. The difference only become apparent if you view the same page multiple times. My suggestion is similar to seeding the PRNG with the userid instead of the time, except that it has better stability properties than that.

One simple implementation could be:

```
answerId^(userId*1299019)
```

With an effective ordering of `OrderBy(score).ThenBy(answerId^(userId*1299019))`

Comment: If you want totally stable ordering select the "oldest" tab. Slightly less stable is the "activity" tab as the most recently edited answer is at the top.

Comment: Both gives me Math error

Comment: @ChrisF I like ordering by score, but I don't like how answers change their order on each refresh if they have the same score. Even if *nothing* happened in between. [at]genesis What do you mean?

Comment: @CodeInChaos: try to put 99252^(194007*1299019)  in windows calc (do not copy it, just rewrite it)

Comment: @genesis: Works just fine for me on the Windows 7 calculator... I get 252,018,779,133

Comment: My example is C# pseudo code. With `^` I mean exclusive-or. And this needs to run in an unchecked context, so that overflows disappear.

Comment: It works for me now. It was giving me some strange error before

Comment: Could somebody explain why they prefer the current ordering over this?

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be better to place user with less-reputation to the top, because [High Reputation Attract Too Many 'Up-Votes'](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/515/the-problem-with-reputation-does-high-reputation-attract-too-many-up-votes) than less-reputated users.

Comment: Personally I don't have anything against that order. But I don't think you will have a chance to convince Jeff of using something that doesn't appear random as tie-breaker. So please compare it with the current ordering.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: I deleted that paragraph 3 mins ago already

Comment: Irrelevant, since [high reputation does not attract upvotes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/515/the-problem-with-reputation-does-high-reputation-attract-too-many-up-votes/99264#99264).

Comment: @Gilles: It'S just your opinion ... But I caught myself clicking upvote just because it was Jon Skeet

Comment: @genesis My opinion is backed by data. If you disagree with my analysis of the data, please tell where you think my analysis is flawed.

Answer (score 1):

If any specific order is needed to distinguish between answers with equal score, I'd order them by age (that means, oldest first). This is fair in the way that, a new answer that simply re-hashes an older answer (as I've often noticed), shouldn't be listed before the older one. I haven't really checked, but somehow I assumed this was the way they were displayed anyway.

Comment: I think it was originally like that, but they changed it to give later answers a better chance and thus mitigate the fastest-gun problem.

Comment: @Code Ah, I didn't know that. To me the order doesn't matter much, since I tend to read before I vote ...

Comment: Order in the context of voting doesn't matter much to me either. But sometimes I refresh the page to check for new answers. And the random change in order makes that annoying.

Comment: @Code Right. This is a context I haven't experienced very often. But I can see the point ...