# User cards are no longer showing reputation or badges across the network

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, design, user-card

I cannot see reputation of any questioner or answerer on their user cards, but editors' rep & badges are still shown.

Questions tab with any filter(new, active) is unaffected.

Mobile sites are unaffected.

It appears to be a network-wide issue.

> [image: questioner's name without rep]
>
> [image: editor and poster]

New contributor banner expands.

> [image: new contributor]

Answer (score 70, accepted):

This was an unintentional slip-up. We were fixing some Google crawler errors for deleted user cards on questions/answers and a set of brackets got missed in the code path that renders schema.org attributes. That meant that this:

```
RenderSchema ? @"<span class=""d-none"" itemprop=""name"">" + 
UserToShow?.ToString() ?? name + "</span>" : ""
```

Ignored everything after the null coalesce operator (`??`) and the missing `</span>` consumed the rep div. We changed it to:

```
RenderSchema ? @"<span class=""d-none"" itemprop=""name"">" + 
(UserToShow?.ToString() ?? name.ToHtmlString()) + "</span>" : ""
```

I'm afraid this was missed during review and I only tested the deleted user case because I'm silly. Apologies for the inconvenience!

Builds are rolling out now.

Comment: Thanks for the quick fix for this!

Comment: SO approves of the extremely technical explanation of the bug! Can't speak for the other sites though :)

Comment: But is the original problem now also fixed for editors?

Comment: Thanks for the detailed dive into the cause, Dean!

Comment: In the US, we call them parentheses. :)

Answer (score 25):

No, I can't. This is because a `span` with class `d-none`, which effectively hides the reputation, etc.

```html
<span class="d-none" itemprop="name">ankii
    <div class="-flair">
        <span class="reputation-score" title="reputation score " dir="ltr">222</span><span title="1 gold badge" aria-hidden="true"><span class="badge1"></span><span class="badgecount">1</span></span><span class="v-visible-sr">1 gold badge</span><span title="2 silver badges" aria-hidden="true"><span class="badge2"></span><span class="badgecount">2</span></span><span class="v-visible-sr">2 silver badges</span><span title="12 bronze badges" aria-hidden="true"><span class="badge3"></span><span class="badgecount">12</span></span><span class="v-visible-sr">12 bronze badges</span>
    </div>
</span>
```

It is all there, just hidden. Removing the class reinstates the card.

I do hope this isn't because of some Tweet again. Possibly some A/B testing stuff that got from Dev to Prod.

---

### TamperMonkey Userscript to fix this

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Fix that reputation
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @include        /^https?:\/\/([^/.]+\.)*(stackexchange.com|stackoverflow.com|serverfault.com|superuser.com|askubuntu.com|stackapps.com|mathoverflow.net)\/(?:q(uestions)?\/\d+)/
// @exclude        *://chat.stackoverflow.com/*
// @exclude        *://chat.stackexchange.com/*
// @exclude        *://chat.*.stackexchange.com/*
// @exclude        *://api.*.stackexchange.com/*
// @exclude        *://data.stackexchange.com/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';

    var userCards = $('div.user-details span.d-none div');

    userCards.each(function(){
        var parent = $(this).parent().parent();
        var element = $(this).detach();
        parent.append(element);
    });
})();
```

Comment: Well, let's tweet about it and see if that nullifies another tweet requesting this ^^.

Comment: Can't be A/B test because looks like 100% of the users have this.

Comment: @Shadow B testing then?

Comment: Good thing I noticed that you posted this userscript before I took the time to make it myself ;)

Comment: @NathanOliver A/A testing. o_O

Comment: Now I see double names...

Comment: Something might be broken with that script.  I installed it and now I can comment.  Had to turn it off to post this.

Comment: True, not sure what. Checking @NathanOliver

Comment: @NathanOliver Fixed now. Remove the jQuery reference.

Comment: @PatrickHofman I still have the same problem with the double names, but I can comment now

Comment: @PatrickHofman Thanks.  I can now comment.  There is still a double name, but that really doesn't matter too much.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton That is because of some weird construction with text and a div within a span. No idea how to get that out yet.

Comment: Heads up: The problem causing this is the <div> being thrown inside the span. If you can somehow use jQuery magic to move the div inside the span out, that's your fix. I think this might be a big though (there's been weirder bugs than this :]). See the code on this page (F12) and compare it to [this random archived version of a random page](https://web.archive.org/web/20191007004522/https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334551/an-apology-to-our-community-and-next-steps) for reference.

Comment: @Zoethetransgirl That is the problem indeed.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton Found a fix

Comment: @Zoethetransgirl Good idea. That fixed it.

Comment: Heads up in case you missed it: [it's a bug, and they're going to fix it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/390271/let-us-opt-out-of-ui-experiments#comment733684_390271).

Comment: Hear, hear! Your script even if not installed fixes the bug. I can see rep and badges again. Pure magic!

Answer (score 12):

> FYI the rep and badges is a bug. There is a fix incoming. – Taryn♦ 4 mins ago

<sup>source: [Let us opt-out of UI experiments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/390271/let-us-opt-out-of-ui-experiments#comment733684_390271) on MSO</sup>

Edit:
So you can see my rep now..

Answer (score 8):

## This is a bug

Don't fret.

[Taryn has confirmed it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/390269/is-so-running-another-experiment-by-hiding-the-user-information-or-is-it-a-bug/390270#comment733693_390269), saying a fix is coming soon.

---

And it is now fixed.

Comment: @ankii thanks. Dean beat me to it by a few seconds, so I hadn't seen his post.

Comment: And it's already fixed

Answer (score 7):

*This is a terrible change.*

## Please put back reputation and badge counts!

**Explanation**: Reputation and badges acknowledge contributions valued by the community.  They provide useful quality signals and were one of the innovations that allowed Stack Overflow to rise above past online Q/A and expertise site failures.  Removing them, or making them any less prominent, would be a ***terrible mistake***.

Comment: Why do you think so?

Comment: Why is everyone assuming this is intentional? SE has had much weirder bugs in the past - at least wait a little to give time for SE to reply before assuming it's intentional

Comment: If this IS intended, then SE should at least have made a post here in meta before implementing it.

Comment: @ankii:  Answer updated with explanation per your request.

Comment: @Renan they've made a lot of changes and then waited for the community to find out before announcing. Weirdly, they do the same with bugs, which makes it impossible to tell apart bugs from intentional, major changes from the outside. They should, but they don't. Hopefully, that changes

Comment: You're too early with getting all worked up and angry: [Employee confirmed on MSO: it's a bug](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/390269/is-so-running-another-experiment-by-hiding-the-user-information-or-is-it-a-bug/390270#comment733693_390269)

Comment: We'd given their QA process too much credit?

Comment: No do NOT put this back! This is a wonderful enhancement! We can eliminate so much prejudice, that information did nothing to improve the quality of this site.

Comment: @Vogon, not to mention, we need the extra space to put pronouns in there.

Comment: @VogonPoet Too late, I'm afraid, the bug's already been fixed. And it really does seem you're the only person who wants this.

Comment: Among the 215 people who experienced the feature over this 30 minutes, you may well be right. Votes over the past decade very much disagree with you.

Comment: This is unfortunate. We sacrifice quality for alleged popularity over the competition. Quality-minded users [really want this to be permanent and have tried for many years](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/515/the-problem-with-reputation-does-high-reputation-attract-too-many-upvotes). So much moderator burden would be removed - no more grudges and hate-voting and other [response biases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Response_bias).

Answer (score 0):

To complete @Patrick Hofman's answer, you can also enable back the reputation by adding this line to CSS customizers such as Stylus or Stylish

```css
div.user-details .d-none  {
    display:block !important;
}
```

Edit: The bug seems to be corrected, my workaround is not needed any more.

Comment: No need, [Employee confirmed on MSO: it's a bug](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/390269/is-so-running-another-experiment-by-hiding-the-user-information-or-is-it-a-bug/390270#comment733693_390269)

Answer (score -8):

This was an accident however it really does need to be implemented in a beta test environment. The data would be invaluable toward resolving long-standing and recurring voter bias issues discussed through the past decade:

Please read 
[Should there be anonymous answers (and questions)?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198/should-there-be-anonymous-answers-and-questions)

And [The problem with reputation: does high reputation attract too many upvotes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/515/the-problem-with-reputation-does-high-reputation-attract-too-many-upvotes)

And  [Why does the reputation need to be publicly displayed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160382/why-does-the-reputation-need-to-be-publicly-displayed)

And [Why is the reputation of a post's author shown on all questions and answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199394/why-is-the-reputation-of-a-posts-author-shown-on-all-questions-and-answers)

This should be a permanent feature. We have asked for this for a decade. Hide the user name as well please.

The GOAL is content-based votes. None of this distracting information works toward that goal. We would become far more objective and expert with such a feature.

Comment: Have you got any evidence to prove that content-based voting isn't taking place ATM?

Comment: While I empathize with your desire to collect data, accidentally springing a partial obfuscation of reputation network-wide is not solid methodology for collecting that data.

Comment: @Script47 - Decades of human psychology. Let me know the last time you participated in a reputable survey that shared everyone else's opinions and reputation going in. I promise you if I show you my paycheck it will conclusively prove that I did not just now invent the concept of [response bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Response_bias). My argument can also be worded, "Let's not snub our noses at good science."

Comment: Except... this isn't a survey. Content can be good or bad irrespective of the users rep. Unless you can categorically prove that the vast majority of users are voting on content for reasons other than quality then I don't see how you can build your case? As for your: '*Let's not snub our noses at good science.*', but isn't good science founded on the principle of evidence? Yet, so far, you have shown none.

Comment: @Script47 - I find the opinion that this is not a survey to be bizarre. What leads you to this opinion? How do you feel it is different? A survey is defined "investigate the opinions or experience of (a group of people) by asking them questions" How is this different?

Comment: @VogonPoet You're a veering off the main point. As SO is my main site, I come to it to either solve problems or find solutions. I don't see how surveys comes into any of that?

Comment: Do you ever consider votes when you look at an answer? The answer may be "no" on sites with black-and-white answers however the majority of sites have responses with varying degrees of quality, which are put to a survey through voting. The vote asks every viewer, "Is this content on topic? Is this content useful? Is this content appropriate? Is this content clear? and Is this content well-researched? These are the survey questions every single SE vote, close vote, & flag vote is an answer to. SE is very much a survey. If you have ever voted on SE, you have completed a survey.