# Why were all my comments deleted?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, comments, specific-question, deleted-comments

Originally(*ie. before the revisions history*), [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20120121/value-type-variable-and-reference-type-variable/20120149#20120149) said you **can't** pass a value type variable by reference.

I have posted [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20120121/value-type-variable-and-reference-type-variable/20120186#20120186) which contradicted the linked one. I have demonstrated that a value type variable **can** be passed by reference using the *ref* keyword.

Immediately after that, the OP of the original answer revised his answer. His first few edits  were not captured by the revision system. The answer's context was wrong...

While his answer attracted the most attention *for being wrong*, my answer was correct from the start but I guess it hasn't been seen by others yet as it didn't receive any up votes...

This felt a bit like a case of [the fastest gun in the west](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem).

I felt a bit omitted, left out, and not appreciated for the contribution as possibly [because the other user has more reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/515/the-problem-with-reputation-does-high-reputation-attract-too-many-upvotes).

Now, I do understand the SO model: the community can revise questions and answers to provide the best possible source of correct information. This is great and I do like the idea. The fact that the question was wrong attracted the community attention. There have been multiple comments pointing out what was wrong and the answer kept being edited.

*If a new user answers and the context of his answer is wrong he is most of the time down voted and comments indicate that his answer is wrong and what is wrong with it. But this case because the user who answered is a higher-rep one nobody actually left a down vote*

So, I have left a few comments too which were deleted. I can't reference them as they are not visible to me but I can't understand what drove the person who flagged my comments for moderators attention. I guess it might have been the OP feeling a bit embarrassed as he was being pointed out all the bads.

I haven't offended anyone in my comments and haven't posted any spam or hate speech. I would appreciate an explanation of why my comments have been deleted? Were they not constructive or too chatty?

Please note: the reason I am asking is: I may not fully understand what the comments section is for - and if I don't, I'd like to make sure I do as I contribute quite a lot to Stack Overflow and it would be better for me to actually understand the mechanism so I don't make others feel uncomfortable and don't feel not appreciated myself.

Comment: Can you roughly remember the actual text of your comments?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If a new user answers and the context of his answer is wrong he is
>   most of the time down voted and comments indicate that his answer is
>   wrong and what is wrong with it.

This experience has varied greatly for me. I've posted answers both as a low rep and medium (25K+) rep user in which I've found errors/improvements months later that no one pointed out or downvoted.

Higher rep does seem to buy you a little trust when the answer includes "gray areas". High rep certainly doesn't offer immunity from downvotes, though sometimes the aforementioned trust extends too far.

*A propos*, it's apparent from the question/answers that not everyone fully understands the underlying concept in c# (and it's a commonly misunderstood topic). Thus, they may not know to downvote or be more tolerant of "work in progress" answers.

Those people actively involved in the comments (who may be more well-versed on the subject) were probably giving the author the chance to fix the answer, since he was engaged and willing to make changes.

Is that the correct approach? it's up to those people casting (or not casting) the downvotes. You didn't downvote the answer either (or you reversed your downvote).

> There have been multiple comments pointing out what was wrong and the
>   answer kept being edited.

If I were the author of the answer, I would audit my own understanding of the topic and/or my ability to communicate it effectively. Downvotes are a definite signal of a problem, but so are comments, sometimes even more so. Anyone can downvote, but not everyone can leave a thoughtful comment disputing the answer.

> I can't reference them as they are not visible to me but I can't
>   understand what drove the person who flagged my comments for
>   moderators attention. I guess it might have been the OP feeling a bit
>   embarrassed as he was being pointed out all the bads.

It's perfectly appropriate to flag a comment if it's no longer relevant. If the author of the answer feels that they've fixed the particular problem then they may want to reduce the noise. And you are correct, they very well may be embarrassed by the mistake and that may be the primary reason they chose to flag it.

If you felt that the comment(s) contained useful information that was not addressed, you could add that information to your own answer.

> [From your comments on Rory's answer] It seems like you're indicating
>   that 90% of the comments might as well be deleted as they are served
>   their purpose? So why weren't the other comments deleted but mine
>   only?

A fair question. Maybe they felt that the corrected answer had fully addressed your comments. Maybe they didn't want to raise more flags.

> While his answer attracted the most attention for being wrong, my
>   answer was correct from the start but I guess it hasn't been seen by
>   others yet as it didn't receive any up votes...

It happens. Being correct from the start isn't always recognized. But even without recognition it's an important personal skill, i.e. being able to confidently state and defend a good answer on the first try. And fast, accurate answers have the chance to earn many upvotes and the occasional Enlightened badge.

Comment: thanks and since I cant reference my comments theres nothing we can really do... but still i feel someone with a bit more power (rep) just had a bad day and overreacted taking me as a target

Answer (score 2):

Comments are ephemeral on Stack Exchange.

If the comments have served their purpose, by causing the OP to edit their post, or to clarify an uncertain point, then they can be removed.

This may be because they were flagged, or maybe a mod just thought it was time for a cleanup - too many comments on a post always makes me want to clean so the Question and Answers can be easily read.

Comment: It seems like you're indicating that 90% of the comments might as well be deleted as they are *served* their purpose? So why weren't the other comments deleted but mine only?

Comment: in this instance, I don't know - I can't see your ones. The ones that remain appear to be helping move towards answers though.

Comment: Not all comments are temporary, even in an ideal world - some useful information simply doesn't fit in a post.