# (Option to) hide the number of votes on an answer

Tags: feature-request

I am not 100% sure (how could I be?), but there are times when I feel myself being biased towards voting for answers because they have already received a lot of votes. If this were true, this would cement early answers with some early votes at the top, because people keep voting for the top-voted answers.

Hypothesizing that I might not be the only one to fall prey to this kind of bias, I propose an option to hide the number of votes on answer. Answers may still be ordered by the number of votes, but they don't have to be visible really (basically hiding whether two subsequent answer are almost tied, 51-50, or very different 100-1).

Answer (score 5):

Votes and score are the most important part of Stack Overflow and any Stack Exchange site.

Hiding them is against the very basic spirit of Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 4):

#### No!

I jump across sites looking for answers. Since time is limited in most cases, I tend to look at answers with the upvotes, and answers from the high reputation users. If this wasn't possible, it would take me a lot of time going through each and every answer to get what I want.

Merely sorting isn't good. What if all the answers are bad? I need to see the upvotes.

See also: [The problem with reputation: does high reputation attract too many upvotes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/515/309993)

Comment: While I understand your concern and your desire to see upvotes - I don't share those. Does any of your arguments hold with regard to my request for an *option* (default: turned off) to hide upvotes?

Comment: @bers if it's your personal issue with biased voting, I'd recommend using custom user scripts to hide the score from your browser page instead of making it a feature for all.