# Feature Request - Private Answers

Tags: feature-request, privacy, anonymous

I ask questions to help other people, but it would be so much easier for me if I could link to the questions, but then they could see my other questions which I don't want them to see. Can you provide a way to put questions on private?

Or maybe allow a question to be asked anonymously?

Comment: Why don't you want them to be able to see your other questions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should there be anonymous answers (and questions)?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198/should-there-be-anonymous-answers-and-questions)

Answer (score 10):

You can ask questions anonymously. Log out and then when asking a question, use the username Anon or something similar. Sure your IP and whatnot may still be recorded, but it isn't tied to your account.